# Confused about getchar() and fflush(stdin) behavior

Tags: c

I thought `getchar()` or `fflush(stdin)` was used to take the newline or space left by the previous input, because the `gets()` function is unable to differentiate between that newline and the input we provide. We did not need those when we use `%s` on the `scanf` function. Why do we need it when we use `%c` or `%d` on the same function?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is that `fflush()` has no defined behavior for input streams, there are some specific implementation defined behaviors. Also, there is `fpurge()` in *glibc* which does what you want.

When using `scanf()` the rule is that it will stop when it finds a white space character as returned by `isspace()`, except when using `%c` which behaves differently as it can capture white spaces, or ignore them all if preceded by a white space.

Also, the `gets()` function is dangerous and was recently removed from the [c](/questions/tagged/c) standard so you should not use it or refer to it as an example.

The `fgets()` function, which is a better version of `gets()` does capture the final `'\n'` if it can, i.e. if the number of characters captured so far does not exceed the value of it's second parameter so you don't need to *flush* anything after it.

You should consider, that `scanf()` not only leaves the last `'\n'` in the input buffer but any white space following it too. So a single `getchar()` is usually not enough, you should `getchar()` as many white spaces as were left there to ensure the apparent behavior of `fflush(stdin)`.